# How to secure that a user can edit only their own ticket

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

So if a user wants to edit their own ticket they can do it from a form. But if they change the ID in the form, they can also edit another user's ticket. How do I prevent this?

```
public function edit(Ticket $ticket)
{
    $user = request()->user()->ticket()->get();

    if ($ticket === $user){
        return view('users.tickets.edit',['ticket' => $ticket,]);
    }
    else{
        abort(403);
    }
}
```

It automatically pick abort 403

This is the user Model

```
public function ticket(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Ticket::class, 'ticket_user');
}
```

This is the ticket model

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'ticket_user');
}
```

Comment: Please explain a little more... The ticket belongs to multiple users and you want to check if the user (that belongs to the users associated with the ticket) can edit the ticket?

Comment: Yes correct but if the user does not belong to the ticket he can not enter that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic itself could look like this:

```
$ticket->users->contains($request->user())
```

In your controller it could look like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function edit(Request $request, Ticket $ticket)
{
    if (! $ticket->users->contains($request->user())) {
        return abort(403);
    }
  
    return view('users.tickets.edit', [
        'ticket' => $ticket
    ]);
}
```

Docs for [`Collection::contains`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-collections#method-contains).

I suggest looking into how you could exclude your authorisation logic into [gates](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#gates) and [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#creating-policies).

Comment: If you suggest using policies, you should write an answer that does so!

Comment: I deliberately suggested them but only written the actual logic because I thought it‘ll go beyond what the author asked for. They are a nice to have but not necessary for his problem to be resolved.

Comment: I just add* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request in the edit controller and use his edit function now it work

Answer (score 0):

The right implementation for me looks like this.

The models:

```
*User
 id
 ...

*Ticket
 id
 ...

 UserTicket
 *id
 *ticket_id
 *user_id
```

When you create a ticket you have to create a new UserTicket for any user is able to edit the ticket.

Then you check if there is a record in UserTicket that has the user_id.

For example:

The Ticket model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(UserTicket::class, User::class);
}
```

And the edit controller

```
public function edit(Ticket $ticket)
{
    $currentUser = request()->user();
    $ticketUsers = $ticket->users;

    // loop each ticketUser and check their id == $currentUser->id

}
```